# Create Azure organization outside of organizational account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a couple open source projects hosted on GitHub where I would like to use Azure pipelines for automated testing, building, and deploying. These projects typically involve collaborating with others outside my institution. My Azure account is an Organizational account for the University where I work. If I create an organization on Azure it ends up being "owned" by my University which means that collaborators have to go through some extra hoops to get access to the Azure organization (become a user or project admin). We've also considered having my collaborator create the organization, but their account is also tied to their institution and has even more restrictions.

Apart from making a separate Azure account on a separate email, is there any way that I can make an organization that isn't "owned" by my University?

Answer (score 0):

You could [create a new DevOps organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/create-organization?view=azure-devops), and disconnect the AAD from **Organization Settings** -- **Azure Active Directory**, then you could add the external users in this organization. In this way, external users won't be added in the azure.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to help. This removed the connection to my University's Active Directory but my collaborator is now getting "401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access." instead of information on creating an account with my University.

Comment: Do you mean your collaborator can not access your Azure Devops (https://dev.azure.com/xxx) after disconnect the AAD?

Comment: Yes. To clarify though, he didn't have access before. My University had some extra step along the lines of "create a guest account to access this University Azure resource". We/he decided not to go through with this in hopes of a cleaner solution (this SO question). Now that I've removed AAD when he clicks on the invite link in the newly sent email (send after I re-add him to the Azure org) he goes directly to a `401` page.

Comment: AAD user is supposed to be able to access DevOps that not in AAD. Could you let the user clean the browser cache and try again?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. My collaborator is still unable to access the organization.  I just removed and re-added him and have asked him to try again.

Comment: Collaborator tried again and got this:
> Your account, name@email.com is not authorized to view this page. Make sure the URL is correct and your account has access. View a list of your organizations here. You may request access by contacting the admin.

Comment: Are you able to provide your organization name? Also, ask the user capture a [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) trace, mask the personal information and share the trace.

Comment: The organization is https://dev.azure.com/pytroll/. Our current workaround is for him to use his personal gmail account instead of his institutions account (which has their own AD link to the accounts). I can ask about fiddler (we are both on linux however so we'll see how the beta goes) and let you know.